# Excluding bad data models during query

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

We have mongo data models that are written by multiple systems; currently, a bug in a different system can corrupt a single document in a collection such that it can no longer be mapped to the correct Java object (for example, a missing `_class` attribute in a subdocument will cause an instantiation exception). When we then query for all documents in the collection using Java, the entire query fails due to the single bad document.

We would like to use an approach which is tolerant of instantiation exceptions; the intent is for any bad documents to be discarded, while still returning objects for all the documents that can be mapped.

Could you please advise the best approach to achieve this outcome?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should be able to mark this field as @Transient in entity to make SpringData to ignore this field in MongoDB communication.